# My Webpage width is twice as wide as the content in it ? Why?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am building building my first Webpage and the width is twice as big as the content in it, I can't find the reason. Here is a link to the codepen, I would really appreciate help, as this got me stuck now for a week. Thank you.

The link:
https://codepen.io/emryyk60/pen/BaLyWXr

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/emryyk60/pen/BaLyWXr?editors=1100" target="_blank">
```

Comment: It looks fine by me.

Comment: The thing is you can scroll to the right and It leads to blank space, I don't know how to fix it. Thanks !

Comment: Oh. I see hold on.

Comment: A lot of tags aren't closed and some tags are closed that shouldn't be. I will be working on it.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax errors, but for a quick fix, adjust the following code:

#### From:

```
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Neutra', sans-serif;  }
```

#### To:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Neutra', sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much !

Comment: @emryyk, Do you mind selecting my answer?